# How do I use a shell command as a launcher shortcut?

Tags: unity, bash, launcher

The following command from terminal works perfectly:

```
sh /home/flux/Downloads/TeamSpeak3-Client-linux_amd64/ts3client_runscript.sh
```

How would I go about adding this as a shortcut, so I can open teamspeak from my Unity Launcher panel on the left without using the terminal?

Comment: @muru definitely a look-alike, only nothing about bash or shell there...

Comment: @JacobVlijm then we'd have to have question for every interpreter out there: the shells, the pythons, the perls, the phps, the bfs, the gnuplots, ....

Comment: @muru I partially agree, but believe mainly the last section (`bash -c`) is somewhat outside the scope of the other question.

Comment: @JacobVlijm I disagree. The scope of the other question is simple creating launchers. It does not say for what. `bash -c` is no different than `firefox -new-window`.

Comment: @muru strictly yes, but running bash commands from the launcher is a subsection of the subject that *could* use some attention on its own; it is a bit more than <application><option> like in firefox. In many cases, subjects on AU are subsections of each other. There is always the decision of where to allow that or not. In this case, I can live with both.

Comment: @JacobVlijm I'd prefer not, in this case. I feel strongly that your answer belongs there and not here. However, that's a flag I will raise if this gets closed.

Comment: My apologies for the duplicate question. I did attempt to find a similar thread. Though the suggestion from your link regarding "Alacarte" was perfect - this tool helped me create the shortcut a lot easier than the manual method. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In its most basic form:

create a `.desktop` file (paste the text below in an empty file):

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Start Teamspeak
Exec=/bin/bash /home/flux/Downloads/TeamSpeak3-Client-linux_amd64/ts3client_runscript.sh
Icon=/path/to/your/icon
Type=Application
```

save the file as `team.desktop` in `~/.local/share/applications` and drag it from there on to the launcher.

#### Explanation

*Running scripts from a .desktop file*

If you run a script in the `Exec=` line from a launcher like this, it works like in the terminal:

- If the script is *not* executable:

  ```
  language /path/to/script.language_extension
  ```
- If the script *is* executable, just:

  ```
  /path/to/script.sh
  ```

  If the script is executable, the language extension is not strictly needed. However, if you use it on the file, also use it in the command.

*Running more complicated shell commands from a .desktop file*

```
Exec=/bin/bash -c "your_complicated_command_here"
(command inside quotes)
```

Comment: Is need to use `sh` here `Exec=sh /home/flux/Downloads/TeamSpeak3-Client-linux_amd64/ts3client_runscript.sh`. `sh` after `Exec=sh`<--this

Comment: @KasiyA I am afraid I don't understand what you mean?

Comment: @KasiyA yes, if the script is not executable the `sh` is needed, otherwise it won't hurt.

Comment: thank you I didn't know that. We can execute script by itself with adding `chmod +x scriptName.sh` and remove the `sh` behind `Exec=`

Comment: IMHO Never use `sh` as the interpreter on scripts unless the script is known to be `sh`-compatible. Prefer `bash`, if the user mentions `bash`.