# Running lubuntu 14.04, easiest, fool proof way, to create a desktop shortcut and to execute sh file from desktop?

Tags: bash, lubuntu

It sounds easy, but hell, it is not.

I want a desktop icon that executes:

```
/home/<username>/dev/intellij/bin/idea.sh
```

if I create a sh file on desktop, it opens with leafpad.

If I create ln -s, nothing happens double clicking it.

The difference in this question to the others, is that this does not use unity. And it requires the solution to be without creating a .desktop file with a [Desktop Entry] that nobody easily seems to understand.

Comment: see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/626434/launching-a-sh-file-from-a-launcher/626513#626513. The fact that you use Lubuntu should not make a difference. Mind that you cannot use `~` in a `.desktop` file, use the command: `/home/<yourname>/intellij/bin/idea.sh`. but the file then needs to be executable. Else use: `/bin/bash /home/<yourname>/intellij/bin/idea.sh`

Comment: See also: http://askubuntu.com/questions/527783/how-do-i-use-a-shell-command-as-a-launcher-shortcut/527787#527787

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I edit/create new launcher items in Unity by hand?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/13758/how-can-i-edit-create-new-launcher-items-in-unity-by-hand)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First Option:

1. Right click the sh file on the desktop
2. Choose Properties
3. Go to the Permissions Tab
4. Checkmark the box that says "Allow Executing File as a Program"
5. Go to the Open With Tab
6. Choose a Terminal-Looking Icon

Second Option:
Install nautilus-open-terminalnautilus-open-terminal package from the universe repositories and run the extra command to configure it:

```
sudo apt-get install nautilus-open-terminal



   nautilus -q && sleep 1 && nautilus -n
```

When you right click the file on the desktop, there should be an option that says Open in Terminal

Comment: actually I could start chrome like this (the shellscript way), it works. Great