# Can you create an executable telnet application on the desktop?

Tags: telnet

I am trying to create a telnet shortcut.  I cant seem to find a way to do this.  Any ideas?

Comment: Assuming the telnet shortcut actually is a command, are you familiar with creating a `.desktop` file with a complicated command? In other words: what is the command you want to make the shortcut run?

Comment: Yes the shortcut is a command.  All I am running is telnet <server> <port>  so telnet server 10025.  I tried to create a .desktop file.  But I had no luck.  did it from the GUI and SSH.

Comment: See this: http://askubuntu.com/a/527787/72216 further below, in the "complicated commands" -section.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I use a shell command as a launcher shortcut?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/527783/how-do-i-use-a-shell-command-as-a-launcher-shortcut)

Comment: Please let me know if it actually solves the problem (or not).

Comment: @JacobVlijm Am I actually creating a script here?  I think thats where im confused.  Would I create a telnet.sh file, and then link it to the .Desktop file?

Comment: Nono, like this: `Exec=/bin/bash -c "your-usual-command-to-run-telnet"` should be the Exec= line. If you make the `.desktop` file executable, you can just double click on it to run the command inside it.

Comment: @JacobVlijm.  I created a simple file that just has Exec=/bin/bash -c "telnet-link" and put it in a telnet.desktop file.  I then did chmod +x telnet desktop.  Then I ran it and it says:

There was an error launching the application.

Comment: Not sure what it sais :) . Re- reading, your question is not a *literal* dupe. The use of the `.desktop` file as a standalone launcher or as a Unity launcher makes no difference however. Let me know if you manage :)

Comment: It doesnt seem to be working.  I must be missing something.  I have tried several times with the .desktop launcher.  I just want to create the link so the user doesnt have to remember the string and type it in every time.

Comment: Could you post a link to the complete `.desktop` file you created? (We'llremove some comments afterwards). Does it need to run in a terminal btw?

Comment: just curious, why didn't you post your .desktop file?

Comment: @JacobVlijm I was getting to that but I got side tracked and saw his post first. :)  The only thing that was different was under Exec I had a link to the file (/home/user/files/telnet.sh)  and in users files telnet.sh was there.  Which was probably my issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a simple desktop file:

- Create a new file in `~/.local/share/applications`

  ```
  nano ~/.local/share/applications/telnet.desktop
  ```
- Add the lines below

  ```
  [Desktop Entry]
  Name=Telnet localhost
  Comment=Telnet client
  Exec=telnet localhost
  Icon=terminal
  Type=Application
  Terminal=true
  Categories=Utility;
  StartupNotify=true
  StartupWMClass=telnet
  ```
- The line `Exec= …`, two possibilities

  1. `Exec=telnet localhost`

     I'm using `localhost` as target host. replace `localhost` with your target host.

  **OR**

  2. `Exec=/full/path/to/your/telnet_script`

     Use your own script if you want, eg

     ```
     #!/bin/bash
     telnet localhost
     ```

     Make the script executable and add the full path to your script to the `Exec=` property

---

[image]

Comment: @JacobVlijm You mean, I should remove my answer?

Comment: @A.B.  Please dont remove it worked nicely.  I was able to create it without the script.  I justr executed the telnet string.  As I agree it seems like its covered alot(because I probably ready every post) After spending hours trying to create it.  It wa s not working.

JacobVlijm thank you as well for your help.  I consider myself a noob.  But am willing to learn.  Becuase who likes Windows :)

Thanks again!!!